# My daughter is not talking to me

Tags: behavior

I am father of a 5 year old kid. Both myself and my wife were working until my daughter was 3.5 years old. Until then my daughter was so caring affectionate towards me, would play with me, would talk to me, we used to go out for a walk. She was also affectionate towards her mom.

We moved from India to Sydney when she was 3.5 years old and my wife left her job to take care of my daughter. Even since then I see a change in behavior of hers. She avoids talking to me, she never listens to my word, she never cares when I am around, she never even bothers to greet me when I come home, she hardly is speaking a word now a days in a day. I am so worried. I never scold her told ate and despite her not talking to me I behave the same. I am really worried about my daughter’s behavior towards me for the past 1.5 years and she is so much affectionate towards her mom respects her and cares for her, but I expect at least 5% towards.

My wife says she can’t do anything for her change in behavior. This is the answer I get from my wife when I ask her why is she behaving like this.

I am so much worried. I spend some time with her and I am not fully occupied. I am the same with her from her birth. I am not sure why such a sudden change in my daughter’s behavior.

Kindly help in case if you have any thoughts to change her thinking towards me.

Answer (score 3):

Try spending some 1:1 time with your daughter in an activity that she likes. Designate a time and activity for it - for example, take her to the park for an hour every Sunday morning. Make it predictable.

She might kick and cry, may not talk to you, behave badly and not enjoy the activity at all, but I'd say try it at least 3 times. Try something else then if it's still causing too much distress.

It need not be outside, your wife can go out by herself and you can spend time with your daughter at home (even if that means that both of you watch her favorite TV show). Your wife also needs some time off from the kid!